# Change page content

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm working on a website not made by me that is build with drupal 7.
I have to change the content of 4 pages that contains some blocks.
How can remove some block from only 4 pages?

Answer (score 1):

Log in with administrator credential and go to `admin/structure/block`. Here you can find all blocks which are available on your site. You can find configure button at the right-hand side of each block like below image.
[image: Block Configuration link]
Click on Configure, it will open a new page with visibility settings for the blocks. At the bottom of the page, you can find settings where you can define the visibility of the block.[image: Visibility Settings]

If your block is visible on all pages then check the first radio button and in textarea enter the URL of those pages where you don't want to display the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visibility settings showing below screenshot. If your condition more complicated please enable php filter module . Then you can also see a php condition option there.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **/admin/structure/block**
2. Hit the **configure** link for which the block you want to remove.
3. In the **visibility settings** choose "All pages except those listed" and enter URL's you don't want to this block.
4. Hit Save block